# Horizontal Scroll View and a gap with overlapping content

Tags: android

After some issues, I now have a working horizontal scroller, it uses a linear layout, with various image views inside, the problem is, I want some of the image views to overlap each other, I achieve this by using

```
myImageView.setX(-100);
```

The problem is, there is a big blank space at the end of the scroller, as if all of the image views widths have been taken into account but as they have been moved back a bit, an empty space has been left.

Is there a way to use a relative layout with a scroller? Or a way to manually decrease the width of the scroller so my overlapping content fits?

Comment: Why don't you use [Gallery](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/crop-gallery-1.png)

Comment: You cant overlap images in gallery!

Comment: Did you see the image. at the top images strip, images are overlapped

Comment: How do I add a gallery? This breaks it, Gallery gallery = new Gallery(this);